# Bootstrap 4 table td width size customize

Tags: php, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I need to increase the rating column width but my w-9 doesn't work.. I want to expand the rating column.

[image: Heres my table]

Here's my table code:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered stick-top">
                <thead class="text-center" id="data">
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Questions</th>
                        <th id="try">Rating</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="body_data">
                    <?php 
                        $jio=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM question")or die ("error");
                        while(list($Question_ID,$Question_Description)=mysqli_fetch_array($jio))
                        { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $Question_ID; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $Question_Description; ?> </td>

                            <?php
                            $q1 = "SELECT * FROM rating ORDER BY Rating_ID ASC";
                            $r1 = $conn -> query($q1);
                            echo "<td class='w-9'";
                            while($row = $r1 -> fetch_object()){
                                echo "<input id='radio' type='radio' name='radio$Question_ID' value='" . $row -> Rating_ID . "' required>". $row -> Rating_ID;"";
                            }
                            echo "</td>";
                             ?>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you check Bootstrap Doc at [Sizing  doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/sizing/)  you will they have included support for **25%, 50%, 75%, 100%  and auto** so basically when you are using `w-9` the class is empty

so if you can't modify css file you need to place the following attribute inside your td tag :

```
<td  style="width:9%">
```